# jQuery navigation menu all menu items expand very quickly when first clicked

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation

I'm working on development for a site here: [site link](http://agra.mc2dev.com/)

When the sidebar navigation is clicked the entire menu expands very quickly on page load and then behaves as it should. I'd like to prevent that from happening.

Here's script:

```
// page init
jQuery(function(){
    initSlideShow();
    initOpenClose();
    initMobileNav();
    initFitVids();
});

// open-close init
function initOpenClose() {
    jQuery('.open-close li').openClose({
        activeClass: 'active',
        opener: '.open',
        slider: '.slide',
        animSpeed: 400,
        effect: 'slide'
    });
    jQuery('.slide li').openClose({
        activeClass: 'active',
        opener: '.ico',
        slider: 'ul',
        animSpeed: 400,
        effect: 'slide'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Render it hidden (on page load)

```
style="display:hidden; visibility: none"
```

and display it on document load

```
$('.open-close li').show();
```